# I want the title of my slides to appear vertically like in the second image

Tags: css, overlay, accordion

This is my menu. As you see, the title of the slides appears horizontally.

[image]

This is how I would like them (in terms of text positioning):

[image]

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jonessie/VRe8W/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRe8W/1/

You can rotate it by rotating the `.image_title a` with the css3 rotation function

```
transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
```

Don't forget all the prefixes, otherwise it won't work in some browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much Danny :) I will Vote Up your answer as soon as I have the reputation

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Thanx.